# Slow Solution from DSolve when Adding Initial Conditions to system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find an analytical solution to the following system of ODEs:

```
uB'[t] == -a*uB[t]*uC[t] + b*uD[t],
uC'[t] == -a*uB[t]*uC[t] + b*uD[t],
uD'[t] == a*uB[t]*uC[t]-b*uD[t]
```

I can find the numerical solution readily with the following:

```
Assuming[uB > 0 && uC > 0 && uD > 0,
  NumericalSol = NDSolve[{
     uB'[t] == -uB[t] uC[t] + uD[t],
     uC'[t] == -uB[t] uC[t] + uD[t],
     uD'[t] == uB[t] uC[t] - uD[t] , 
     uB[0] == 1, 
     uC[0] == 1, 
     uD[0] == 0}, 
    {uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]];
```

And I can find the general closed-form solution with this:

```
ExactSol = DSolve[{
    uB'[t] == -a*uB[t] uC[t] + b*uD[t],
    uC'[t] == -a*uB[t] uC[t] + b*uD[t],
    uD'[t] == a*uB[t] uC[t] - b*uD[t]},
   {uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]}, t] // Simplify
```

But as soon as I include initial conditions to my analytical solution to reproduce the numerical solution:

```
ExactSol = DSolve[{
    uB'[t] == -a*uB[t] uC[t] + b*uD[t],
    uC'[t] == -a*uB[t] uC[t] + b*uD[t],
    uD'[t] == a*uB[t] uC[t] - b*uD[t],
    uB[0] == 1, 
    uC[0] == 1, 
    uD[0] == 0},
   {uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]}, t] // Simplify
```

The code tries to evaluate but never finishes - is there a clear reason why the constrained solution would be difficult to obtain? What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is having hard time solving for $c_i$, from initial conditions. We can do it manually

```
ode1 = uB'[t] == -a*uB[t] *uC[t] + b*uD[t];
ode2 = uC'[t] == -a*uB[t] *uC[t] + b*uD[t];
ode3 = uD'[t] == a*uB[t] *uC[t] - b*uD[t];
ic = {uB[0] == 1, uC[0] == 1, uD[0] == 0};
exactSol = 
 First@DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3}, {uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]}, t] // 
  FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
eq1 = uB[t] /. exactSol
eq2 = uC[t] /. exactSol
eq3 = uD[t] /. exactSol
```

[image]

```
sol = Solve[{1 == eq1 /. t -> 0, 1 == eq2 /. t -> 0, 
   0 == eq3 /. t -> 0}, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}]
```

[image]

```
 sol = First@Normal[sol, ConditionalExpression]
```

[image]

```
 exactSol /. sol
```

[image]

Notice, the solutions are not unique!. There is arbitrary $c_4$ in them. You set this to any value in Z (I take this back. Any integer value for $c_4$ gives the same solution. So any integer value for `C[4]` will work).

```
 exactSol /. sol/. C[4]->1
```

[image]

### Verify against numerical

```
Assuming[uB > 0 && uC > 0 && uD > 0, 
 NumericalSol = 
  First@NDSolve[{uB'[t] == -uB[t] uC[t] + uD[t], 
     uC'[t] == -uB[t] uC[t] + uD[t], uD'[t] == uB[t] uC[t] - uD[t], 
     uB[0] == 1, uC[0] == 1, uD[0] == 0}, {uB, uC, uD}, {t, 0, 1}]];
Plot[Evaluate[{uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]} /. NumericalSol], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
newSol = exactSol /. sol /. C[4] -> 1;
Plot[Evaluate[{uB[t], uC[t], uD[t]} /. newSol /. {a -> 1, 
    b -> 1}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]